# Searching for words in textarea

Tags: java, full-text-search

I am building a custom a `find and replace` in java. I browse a text file and load the contents in a textarea. Now I have a textBox, where I input a text that needs to be searched.

What is the best way to search the text. I know a way using `string.indexOf()`, but I also need highlighting. So please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all read [Text and New Lines](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/) for information on how to get the text to search.

Then to highlight the text your find you need to use a Highlighter. The code is something like:

```
Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = 
    new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.cyan );

int offset = text.indexOf(searchWord);
int length = searchWord.length();

while ( offset != -1)
{
    try
    {
        textPane.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + length, painter);
        offset = text.indexOf(searchWord, offset+1);
    }
    catch(BadLocationException ble) { System.out.println(ble); }
}
```

Comment: Camicker, how to remove the previous highlight

Answer (score 0):

indexOf is the easiest way, but might not be the fastest way.

Why isn't indexOf working for you? You will get the index of the match, and you know the length of the match, so just highlight the text that matched.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with my text editor. I didn't use a highlighter though, I used

```
textArea.select(int i1, int i2); //where i1 is where your selection begins and i2 is where it ends.
```

also an easy way to find and replace is:

```
textArea.setText(textArea.getText().replaceAll(String string1, String string2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Find What?");
final int l1 = jTextArea1.getText().indexOf(inputValue);
final int l2 = inputValue.length();

if (l1 == -1) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Search Value Not Found");
} else {
    jTextArea1.select(l1, l2+l1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.getSource() == btnSearch && !searchWord.getText().isEmpty()) {

    Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = 
        new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.cyan );

    templateArea.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();

    int offset = templateArea.getText().indexOf(searchWord.getText());
    int length = searchWord.getText().length(); 

    while ( offset != -1)
    {
        try
        {
             templateArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + length, painter);
             offset = templateArea.getText().indexOf(searchWord.getText(), offset+1);
        }
        catch(BadLocationException exception) { System.out.println(exception); }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation of the solution. Not just code.