# Text search in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, full-text-search, components, jtextarea

What is the command(s) to search for a keyword (or any word that interests us) in the `JTextArea` - NetBeans?

I've been searching within the stackoverflow but with no result so far, possibly I've missed it.  I am new to this environment, a detailed explanations would be beneficial.

Comment: 'Netbeans' is not relevant to this, since you might do it exactly the same way in Eclipse, or a text editor.

Comment: Please refer to this question [Searching for words in textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909419/searching-for-words-in-textarea). Hope this what you need.

Comment: thank you for your assistance, i decided to save the text from the jTextArea into the file and work with the file independently. Thats somehow better when creating the lexical analyzer.

Comment: Duplicate question with a better answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13438455/1000011

Answer (score 3):

1. have look at [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)
2. in the bottom of tutorial is described one of, but very simple way