# Positioning objects in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jcombobox

I have a simple panel with a comboBox, but I'm having a problem with the comboBox, taking up too much space, I can't seem to resize it.

I have the code:

```
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 1));
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
panel.add(new JLabel("Type:    "));
JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox(labels);
panel.add(comboBox1);

frame.add(panel);

frame.setSize(550,300);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Where labels is an array of strings, this is how my comboBox looks after running:

[image]

If I try to change the size of the comboBox using 
setSize(), it doesn't seem to do anything?
As I still get the same sized comboBox.
Any ideas?

Comment: Use a different layout manager, maybe a `GridBagLayout`

Comment: Hmm what would be the syntax for that, for setLayout?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21659516/418556) that uses `GroupLayout` (via a generalized helper method).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use a `GridBagLayout`, which gives you a little more control over the layout, something like...

[image: GridBagLayout]

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
panel.add(new JLabel("Type: "));
panel.add(new JComboBox(new String[]{"This is a test"}));
```

or if you want the components to be aligned to the left, maybe something like...

[image: Aligned]

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
panel.add(new JLabel("Type: "));
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
panel.add(new JComboBox(new String[]{"This is a test"}), gbc);
```

See [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: Hmm,  but I wouldn't be able to position it to the far left? And what if I wanted to place things below it, of a type, and combobox, as well.

Comment: Yes, see update.  Yes, you can supply different constraints, including the `gridx`/`gridy` positions of the components.  `GridBagLayout` is among the most flexible of the layout managers, see the linked tutorial for more details

Comment: Hmm, do textfields + labels not work with this layout? Something like panel.add(t,gbc); where t is a JTextArea, which only seems to print the label infront of it, i.e "Type". But I get no viewable textArea as output.

Comment: Yes, it does work, very well, with mixed controls.  You may need to specify the `gridx`/`gridy` positions of your controls though

Comment: [For example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437865/java-scroll-to-specific-text-inside-jtextarea/13438455#13438455)

Comment: Ahh sorry seems the TextArea was viewable, but only once I maximixed the Window, my bad. Thanks anyway