# Search Box for JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, search, jframe, jtextarea

I have made a program, it has show file option, means I have a txt file in which some information is store and when I click on show button it shows in a `JTextArea`.

I have one problem - I have make a `JTextField` and wanted to write something in that text field and have it search for that word in the text area.

The problem is I found codes with highlighter which highlight the word, but 
I want code when I write showing in that search box, the text area automatically scroll down to that word, but don't cancel words around that search word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been answered here: 
[Java - Scroll to specific text inside JTextArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437865/java-scroll-to-specific-text-inside-jtextarea)

Once you have the position `pos`, you can scroll the JTextField to it using this:

```
// Get the rectangle of the where the text would be visible...
Rectangle viewRect = textArea.modelToView(pos);
// Scroll to make the rectangle visible
textArea.scrollRectToVisible(viewRect);
```

Comment: position how?? i am new to java .. so what about pos?? how to set it?

Comment: pos is the character position of the text that you want to scroll to.

Comment: so i just have to make its method only ,