# Scroll to a position in a text area when the button clicked.

Tags: java, swing

It's easy to create HTML link locations like [this sample](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations), but now I'm talking about Java swing.

Lets assume I've created 5 `JButton`s: `firstButton`, `secondButton`, `thirdButton`, `fourthButton` and `fifthButton`.
Then I put all text information in a `JTextArea txtInform`.

When I click `firstButton`, information for `firstButton` will be displayed to the top of `txtInform`.

When I click `secondButton`, information for `secondButton` will be displayed to the top of `txtInform`.

And so forth for the next buttons. All buttons must work like [this sample](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_locations).
How can I do that?

**Note:** I know how to create components (like JButton, JTextArea, etc) in java swing. Please don't tell me only to read the tutorial of [Swing Class API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) or other [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). I have read the Swing Class API tutorial and [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) but I don't find any specific tutorial for this problem yet. If you ever read specific tutorial like what I'm asking here, please let me know.

**Edit:**

**Updated:** What I really need is to scroll to a position in a text area when the button clicked.

Below is the my code so far, I created it in netbeans. I use hightlight from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909419/searching-for-words-in-textarea).

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package gui_001;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultHighlighter;
import javax.swing.text.Highlighter;

/**
 *
 * @author MyScript
 */
public class sampleFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form sampleFrame
     */
    public sampleFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        firstButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        secondButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txtInform = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        thirdButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        fourthButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        fifthButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        firstButton.setText("First Button");
        firstButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                firstButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        secondButton.setText("Second Button");
        secondButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                secondButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        txtInform.setText("*First*");
        txtInform.append("\n");
        txtInform.append("All first information are here..");
        txtInform.append("\n\n\n\n");
        txtInform.append("**Second**");
        txtInform.append("\n");
        txtInform.append("All second information are here..");
        txtInform.append("\n\n\n\n");
        txtInform.append("***Third***");
        txtInform.append("\n");
        txtInform.append("All third information are here..");
        txtInform.append("\n\n\n\n");
        txtInform.append("****Fourth****");
        txtInform.append("\n");
        txtInform.append("All fourth information are here..");
        txtInform.append("\n\n\n\n");
        txtInform.append("*****Fifth*****");
        txtInform.append("\n");
        txtInform.append("All fifth information are here..");
        txtInform.setColumns(20);
        txtInform.setLineWrap(true);
        txtInform.setRows(5);
        txtInform.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txtInform);

        thirdButton.setText("Third Button");
        thirdButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                thirdButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        fourthButton.setText("Fourth Button");
        fourthButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                fourthButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        fifthButton.setText("Fifth Button");
        fifthButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                fifthButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(76, 76, 76)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(secondButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(firstButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(thirdButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(fourthButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(fifthButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(64, 64, 64)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(71, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(76, 76, 76)
                .addComponent(firstButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(secondButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(thirdButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(fourthButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(fifthButton, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(44, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 305, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(90, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(595, 477));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void secondButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        String text = txtInform.getText();
        String second = "**Second**";
        int i = text.indexOf(second);
        int pos = txtInform.getCaretPosition(); 

        Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.BLUE );

        int offset = text.indexOf(second);
        int length = second.length();

        while ( offset != -1)
        {
            try
            {
                txtInform.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + length, painter);
                offset = text.indexOf(second, offset+1);
            }
            catch(BadLocationException ble) { System.out.println(ble); }
        }

    }                                            

    private void firstButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        String text = txtInform.getText();
        String second = "*First*";
        int i = text.indexOf(second);
        int pos = txtInform.getCaretPosition(); 

        Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.BLUE );

        int offset = text.indexOf(second);
        int length = second.length();

        while ( offset != -1)
        {
            try
            {
                txtInform.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + length, painter);
                offset = text.indexOf(second, offset+1);
            }
            catch(BadLocationException ble) { System.out.println(ble); }
        }
    }                                           

    private void fifthButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        String text = txtInform.getText();
        String second = "*****Fifth*****";
        int i = text.indexOf(second);
        int pos = txtInform.getCaretPosition(); 

        Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.BLUE );

        int offset = text.indexOf(second);
        int length = second.length();

        while ( offset != -1)
        {
            try
            {
                txtInform.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + length, painter);
                offset = text.indexOf(second, offset+1);
            }
            catch(BadLocationException ble) { System.out.println(ble); }
        }
    }                                           

    private void fourthButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
         String text = txtInform.getText();
        String second = "****Fourth****";
        int i = text.indexOf(second);
        int pos = txtInform.getCaretPosition(); 

        Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.BLUE );

        int offset = text.indexOf(second);
        int length = second.length();

        while ( offset != -1)
        {
            try
            {
                txtInform.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + length, painter);
                offset = text.indexOf(second, offset+1);
            }
            catch(BadLocationException ble) { System.out.println(ble); }
        }
    }                                            

    private void thirdButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
         String text = txtInform.getText();
        String second = "***Third***";
        int i = text.indexOf(second);
        int pos = txtInform.getCaretPosition(); 

        Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter( Color.BLUE );

        int offset = text.indexOf(second);
        int length = second.length();

        while ( offset != -1)
        {
            try
            {
                txtInform.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + length, painter);
                offset = text.indexOf(second, offset+1);
            }
            catch(BadLocationException ble) { System.out.println(ble); }
        }
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(sampleFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(sampleFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(sampleFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(sampleFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new sampleFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton fifthButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton firstButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton fourthButton;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JButton secondButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton thirdButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea txtInform;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Do you know what an `ActionListener` is?

Comment: Did you try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Comment: @kdgregory, Of course I do. I just confuse how to put text in txtInform to the top of txtInform  when button clicked. Okay, I can implement any events in button's ActionListener. My question: what's is the event that I must implement in it?

Comment: "what's is the event that I must implement in it?" In the `actionPerformed`, use `textArea.setText` or `textArea.append` with the information as an argument. I suggest you post some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Hirak, I already read them and tried mostly of them. But, I don't find any specific part tutorials as I ask here.I know how to implement ActionListener and event in JButton. But I still confuse how to put text in txtInform to the top of txtInform  when button clicked. My question: what's is the event that I must implement in it so the text of information for the button will be displayed to the top of txtInform ?

Comment: You don't need to implement any event, that's what the listener does for you. In your `ActionListener`, you call `insert()` on your `JTextArea`. I recommend posting your current code, preferably a shorter version with one button and one text field.

Comment: @user1803551, I've added the code. That's what I've tried so far.

Comment: @kdgregory, I've added the code. That's what I can do so far. What I need is when I click a button, information for it will be displayed directly. For example in my code, information for first code is 'hiding' because txtInform scroll down. Then, when I click firstButton, txtInform should be scroll up and display information for first button. Any idea to solve this?

Comment: So your question is not about inserting text, but about scrolling to a certain location in the text area?

Comment: Also, does the text in the text area change during runtime?

Comment: @user1803551, Yes, scrolling to a certain location in txtInform after clicking a button. The text in textarea never change.

Comment: OK, I'll post an answer soon, but tell me where in the title or the body of the question did you mention anything along the lines of "I want to scroll to a position in a text area"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code with some changes. When pressing a button, the text area will be scrolled to the location of the text and *only* that text will be highlighted.

```
public class SampleFrame extends JFrame {

    private static JTextArea txtInform = new JTextArea();
    private static final String TEXT = "*First*\nAll first information are here..\n\n\n\n" +
            "**Second**\nAll second information are here..\n\n\n\n" +
            "***Third***\nAll third information are here..\n\n\n\n" +
            "****Fourth****\nAll fourth information are here..\n\n\n\n" +
            "*****Fifth*****\nAll fifth information are here..";

    public SampleFrame() {

        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(txtInform);
        JButton firstButton = new JButton("First Button");
        JButton secondButton = new JButton("Second Button");
        JButton thirdButton = new JButton("Third Button");
        JButton fourthButton = new JButton("Fourth Button");
        JButton fifthButton = new JButton("Fifth Button");

        firstButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener("*First*"));
        secondButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener("**Second**"));
        thirdButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener("***Third***"));
        fourthButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener("****Fourth****"));
        fifthButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener("*****Fifth*****"));

        txtInform.setText(TEXT);
        txtInform.setColumns(20);
        txtInform.setRows(5);
        txtInform.setLineWrap(true);
        txtInform.setWrapStyleWord(true);

        GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(76, 76, 76)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(secondButton, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(firstButton, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(thirdButton, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(fourthButton, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(fifthButton, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(64, 64, 64)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 265,
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addContainerGap(71, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(76, 76, 76)
                .addComponent(firstButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30,
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(secondButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31,
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(thirdButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 31,
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(fourthButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32,
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(fifthButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 32,
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(44, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 305,
                            GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE).addContainerGap(90, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(595, 477));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

        private int offset, length;
        private final Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.BLUE);

        private MyActionListener(String chapter) {

            offset = TEXT.indexOf(chapter);
            length = chapter.length();
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            txtInform.setCaretPosition(offset);
            txtInform.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();
            try {
                txtInform.getHighlighter().addHighlight(offset, offset + length, painter);
            } catch (BadLocationException ble) {
                ble.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                new SampleFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

- Class names start with uppercase per Java naming conventions.
- Make your code present a logical order of the lines. It's clearer to initialize all buttons one after the other and not shove in the middle a scroll pane initialization.
- Don't create fields when you can create local variables (all your buttons and scroll pane).
- Prepare a single string with the text that should be displayed instead of calling append for every line (if you are not doing that already).
- Create 1 action listener for all the buttons since it has a similar function for all of them - reusable code.

You'll profit a lot if you write the GUI yourself and not with a builder.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks you for your comments, answer and edit. I've accepted this as the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

Simple example

```
public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JTextField textField = null;
public static void main(final String[] args) { 
Main main =  new Main();
main.textField= new JTextField("Sample");
JButton btn1 = new JButton("Button1");
btn1.addActionListener(main);
JButton btn2 = new JButton("Button2");
btn2.addActionListener(main);

main.add(main.textField);
main.add(btn1);
main.add(btn2);
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setTitle("Simple example");
frame.setSize(300, 200);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.add(main);
frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    textField.setText(e.getActionCommand());
    repaint();

}

}
```

Comment: -1 for sloppy code (aside from indentation, what's that `repaint()` doing, and why are you modifying the component hierarchy on the main thread?), and for aiding and abetting a copy-and-paste coder.